# C# Setting Wallpaper from Current working Directory, getting Error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'C:\Saitama.png'

Tags: c#, xaml

Hello so i ran in a Problem that i could't fix since some days and i thought you people could help me. I want to set the Wallpaper Image from my working directory. It's like this
[Directory how i pasted the Image that should be the Wallpaper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1wbZ.png)

and my Method to set it as a Wallpaper is this

```
public sealed class Wallpaper
{
    const int SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20;
    const int SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
    const int SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, string lpvParam, int fuWinIni);

    public enum Style : int
    {
        Tiled,
        Centered,
        Stretched
    }

    public static void Set(string imgPath)
    {
        string exeDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(exeDir);

        var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imgPath);
        string tempPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), "wallpaper.bmp");
        img.Save(tempPath, ImageFormat.Bmp);

        var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\Desktop", true);

        key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", 1.ToString());
        key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", 0.ToString());


        SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, tempPath, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
    }
}
```

And i want to set the Image Wallpaper like this

```
Wallpaper.Set(@"/Saitama.png");
```

But everytime i get this Error

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'C:\Saitama.png'

That C:\Saitama.png works when i want to set that Image as the Source on XAML but not on this code i have to give a full Path why? And how could I make it that i can give the path like above?

Please help thanks :D

Comment: If `C:\Saitama.png` really exists as file (i am going to blindly assume this even though i have no way of verifying), you might perhaps have "crap" Unicode characters there in the `imgPath` string that don't render visibly but will be treated as part of the path of the file to be loaded/accessed (there are a number of such "invisible" characters in Unicode). For troubleshooting and verifying whether that is the case or not, dump the `imgPath` string into a char array (imgPath.ToCharArray() or something to that effect) and in the debugger inspect each character in this array individually.

Comment: But frankly in all honesty, even without being able to inspect the `C:\ ` directory on your machine myself i would rather tend to bet on there being really no file named "Saitama.png" in `C:\ `...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace There is no such file in C:\ and as i said i want to use the path of the current working directory not the full path. The Program uses somehow only the full path and not the current working directory path

Comment: But you also said "_That C:\Saitama.png works when i want to set that Image as the Source on XAML_" Your question seems to send mixed signals. And if you want to use current directory, why did you then specify the root directory in the given imgPath "/Saitama.png"?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace in xaml it automatically uses the current working directory in the wallpaper set code it uses the full path

Comment: Is it a requirement for one to know XAML details to correctly translate what you say about files into plain English? If so, my apologies for having bothered you, because i have then to admit that i lack the prerequisites to make sense of your question...

Answer (score -1):

Well i didn't found a good Answer but this still makes it's job. I just made Setup Wizard and that Wizard just downloades the Images in the selected Folder and then the Program just uses the Full Path of the Destination where the Image is. I hope i could help someone!